# Coverting Java ArrayList to Vector using java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I know this is a simpler question.

But is it possible to convert given list of objects `List<Person>` and convert it into `Vector<PersonName>` using **Java Streams API**

```
public class Person {        
     String name;
     String lastName;
     int age;
     float salary;
}

public class PersonName {
     String name;
     String lastName;
}
```

Comment: You don't need streams: `new Vector<>(list)`

Comment: Why must it be made with streams?

Comment: But how will it then consider that in Vector we have only name and lastName and not age and salary?

Comment: Well, you should explain in the question that the list consists of both `Person`s and `PersonName`s.

Comment: My bad. I did frame the question same way but missed to mention that in typo.

Comment: The Output demands vector in the code.

Comment: then most probably that is ancient code... there are (much) better options than a `Vector`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should really make a constructor and/or make `PersonName` extend `Person`. But here is a solution that does not use either:

```
ArrayList<Person> list = ...;
Vector<PersonName> vect = list.stream().map(t -> {
    PersonName name = new PersonName();
    name.lastName = t.lastName;
    name.name = t.name;
    return name;
}).collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new));
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a two argument constructor for the `PersonName` type and then you can do:

```
Vector<PersonName> resultSet =
               peopleList.stream()
                         .map(p -> new PersonName(p.getName(), p.getLastName()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new));
```

Comment: even better would be to create a static method for that... `stream().map(Utility::transform)...` also since there is *just* mapping, without any filtering here, it might be good to specify the initial capacity of the `Vector`

Comment: @Eugene I don't see why creating a static method for the transformation would be better apart from hiding the `new PersonName(p.getName(), p.getLastName())` into another method. which by all means is not worthwhile to refactor to a method.